# Browser without tag auto-closing behaviour

Tags: html, browser

We have legacy project full of templates. Some of them contain invalid HTML (with unclosed pair tags and so on) which can cause us a lot of problems. Today we were investigating why **PhpBrowser in Codeception** cannot click on element, which actually could be seen in regular browser for whole day.

The problem was forgot `</div>` element which caused troubles to PhpBrowser with finding link in this **div**.

What would I like is to have a browser which won't **auto-close all tags** to make HTML document "valid". Is there **any way how to turn this behaviour off** in any of those modern browsers we all use today?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there are no browsers that do this. You should probably look into an HTML validator and automated testing of your generated HTML.

Comment: Can you recommend me any tool to do automated testing of our generated HTML, please?

Comment: I'm looking for something similar. Hopefully Chrome will add a toggle button that doesn't auto close your HTML tags. So it's easier to find bugs.